# Recreate local copy of sql server database for server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that is stored locally on my desktop computer. I've made many changes since the original SQL Script and in hindsight I should have kept a record of the changes.

Now I want to recreate this database on a server. Is there any way I can generate a script that will allow me to create the database with it's contents on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could backup the database, copy the .bak file to the server and then restore it there.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a SQL compare tool that will replicate the changes on the server.

- **AdeptSQL** is brilliant, a trial version can be downloaded here: http://www.adeptsql.com/download.htm
- Or a good free tool is **OpenDBDiff** (http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/releases/view/51995) but it's not quite as intuitive.
- If you want to replicate **data** as well, you need a tool that will also do data. The shareware version of **SqlDBDiff** (30 day trial) will be able to do that: http://www.sqldbtools.com/Downloads.aspx?ProductId=1
- Redgate's product is talked about a lot, but you have to cough up some $$.

This post might be useful as a reference to other potential tools:
[Is there an open source SQL Server DB compare tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792/is-there-an-open-source-sql-server-db-compare-tool)

Or you can create a database backup and restore it on the server, if downtime doesn't matter. This can cause problems sometimes with logins etc, but it's not too much hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is your local DB on the server, just backup and restore your local DB on the server.

But I'm guessing that you've made schema changes and / or static data changes which need to be propogated over the server, since you need to retain interim data on the server.

Schema changes can be found using a tool such as [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) or VS DBpro, scripted, and run on the server.